# What is the fastest algorithm for finding subsets that add up to a number?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'm trying to create a model that predicts the outcome of the 2016 Election. One algorithm I'll need is that of finding all the possible combinations of states that can add up to 270 electoral votes. So the setup is like

```
const electoralVotesToWin = 270; 
const states = [
   { Name: "Virginia", ElectoralVotes: 13 },
   { Name: "North Carolina", ElectoralVotes: 15 },
   ... 
];
```

and my desired outcome is like

```
var stateCombos = [
    [ "Virginia", "North Carolina", ... ],
    [ "Virginia", "North Carolina", ....], 
    ...
];
```

Let me know if I need to explain it better.

Is there any better algorithm than the brute force approach that find every subset of states? Either way, anyone here have an elegant and compact, but not necessarily efficient, solution?

Comment: This is classic 0-1 Knapsack Problem with weight==size. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem . For the total size of 270, and item number <= number of states,  a simple DP should give you the result instantly. Some one even asked the same question on quora https://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-way-to-print-out-all-solutions-to-the-0-1-Knapsack-problem-using-dynamic-programming-in-O-nC-time

Comment: To add to @lavin's comment: The problem of finding *one* set of states whose votes add up to exactly 270 is NP-hard, but (if such a set of states exists) you'll find *one such* solution for this particular problem very quickly using the DP algorithm given at that link.  Finding *all* solutions is "quick" too -- in the sense of O(n) per solution, by tracing back through the DP matrix -- but there could be an exponential number of them.  Also if you want to find all solutions that add up to *at least* 270, then you need to modify the DP recurrence slightly.

Comment: @lavin isn't the knapsack problem finding one combination which maximizes the weight while staying below the given limit - whereas OP is asking for all combinations which sum up to exactly the given limit?

Answer (score 0):

This may need some further live testing, but a recursive function could be used to create combinations until the target has been reached (or in this implementation, until there is no remainder):

```
function getStates(arr, rem){    
    var res = [], el;
    while(arr.length){
        [el, ...arr] = arr;        
      if(el.ElectoralVotes >= rem) 
            res.push([el]); //total reached
      else{
        for(var s of getStates(arr,rem - el.ElectoralVotes)) //try to reach total with remainder        
          res.push([el, ...s]);
      }
    }
   return res;
}


var res= getStates(states, electoralVotesToWin);
```

[Test fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o0yLn99g/2/)

NB, for testing the original object was used, but to get only the names, simply change the lines where the element is pushed into the array, so only the name is pushed, for example:[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o0yLn99g/3/)